# Is it possible to keep Socket.IO client socket active across pages, or simply reconnect?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, webrtc, socket.io-1.0

Is it in any way possible that:

- A Socket.IO connection is setup on a certain page
- Upon browsing to another page:

  - Or: The socket is retrieved and re-used from cookies (or similar)
  - Or: The client is reconnected to the socket with the **same socket ID** (since the socket ID is linked to a specific session in my case), on the other page.

I need the connection to stay persistent across pages for my application (for synchronising behaviours across multiple devices using the Socket.IO connection).

If it is not possible at all, does WebRTC have the same limitation? Maybe I could use WebRTC in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If using single-page-application it is quite simple `create connection in root element and use it everywhere.`

If not using single-page-application some workaround are as follows:

e.g. we have pages a.html, b.html

1st way(using iframes):

```
  1. Wrap all your pages in some iframe let x
  2. Make socket connection in it let mySocketObj
  2. Case 1: a.html/b.html are on different origin:
        > give a xhr/fetch request of a.html/b.html
        > create an iframe tag inside x  let y(don't set any src so as default it will be about:blank)
        > open doc of y and put content of xhr/fetch inside it close doc of y
      Case 2: a.html/b.html are on same origin:
        > create an iframe tag inside x let y.
        > set source as a.html/b.html 
  3. add a dynamic script in y as below:
        window.top.mySocketObj = window. mySocketObj
  4. use window.mySocketObj for socket events.
```

2nd Way(using browser extension):

```
  1. Make socket connection in extension environment let mySocketObj.
  2. Call/Message extension environment for socket events.
```

3rd way(By altering content page):

```
  1. Make socket connection in main page let mySocketObj.
  2. give a xhr/fetch request of a.html/b.html.
  3. put response content in current doc without changing doc/window objects.
  4. use mySocketObj for socket events.
```